# Total ways of choosing 7 snacks out of 5 selections

Tags: combinatorics

You have to purchase 7 snacks to get yourself through your late night study session. The local store only has a selection of 5 snacks. What is the total number of ways you can choose snacks for the night?

I thought this can be interpreted as "how many solutions are there for non-negative $x_i$ such that
$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 7$
where $x_i$ is the $i$'th snack selection.
So the solution is just $\begin{pmatrix}7+5-1\\5-1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}11\\4\end{pmatrix}.$

However, the solution says that it is actually $\begin{pmatrix}11\\5\end{pmatrix}$.

Another question similar to this was
"A salad bar allows you to choose 9 different toppings from 11 possible choices. How many salads are possible (you can choose the same topping more than once)."
which has the solution of $\begin{pmatrix}19\\11\end{pmatrix}$ when I think it should it  $\begin{pmatrix}19\\10\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: The book must have typo'd. Both your answers are correct.

Comment: Thanks. It's reassuring that I got the interpretations correctly.

Comment: For the second one, if it said instead: "you CANNOT choose the same topping more than once", does that mean we find the number of solutions to  
$$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_{11} = 9$$ where $$x_i \leq 1$$?

Comment: Yes; the answer for that is of course $\binom{11}9$.

Comment: I thought it'd be $\begin{pmatrix}12\\10\end{pmatrix}$ after using the substitution $y_i = 1-x_i \geq 0$

Comment: Sometimes reducing the problem into an equation isn't the best thing to do. Look at the problem as it's presented. It's like you're placing pegs to indicate which topping you want. Then obviously the answer is as I had said earlier. Indeed, we Singaporeans were always taught to pronounce $\binom nk$ as n choose k...